# Xamarin.iOS SQLiteAsyncConnection randomly fails to read data and returns null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

SQLiteAsyncConnection randomly fails  without any exception to read data when UI is kept busy say fast scrolling or frequent tab switch. Though value is there it returns null. I am checking for key/value in local db and if value is there , then I do logical switches . However read fails and returns null in random scenarios. Observed in Xamarin.ios

Anyone has faced this issue ? How to deal with this issue.

I am opening connection as below :
private readonly Func connectionFactory;
private SQLiteAsyncConnection connection;
protected BaseSqLiteAsyncLocalRepo(ISQLitePlatformContext platformContext)
        {
            if (platformContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("SQLite platform context is null");
            }

```
        var connectionWithLock = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock (platformContext.Platform, new SQLiteConnectionString (platformContext.PlatformDatabaseFolderPath, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false));
        connectionFactory = () => connectionWithLock;
    }

    protected override SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection 
    {
        get
        {
             return connection ?? (connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(connectionFactory));
        }
    }
```